# How to create 2 x 2 grid layout using Collection View?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to create 2x2 grid layout using collection view.

I have used below code. It's kind of working fine for iPhone 5 but with tweaks. I am trying to write code that can be used on all screen sizes. This is not working on iPhone 6.

```
public func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if let cell1 = cell as? CollectionViewCell {
            return cell1
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let padding: CGFloat =  20
        let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding

        return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: collectionViewSize/2+15)
    }

 public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        insetForSectionAt section: Int
        ) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(
            top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5
        )
    }

    public func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }
```

I am trying to achieve following layout:
[image: Expected]

In future this grid can be like 2 columns only and N rows. Each row will always have 2 items.

Comment: What is the issue on iPhone 6?

Comment: In iPhone 6, space between two rows increases. Even in iPhone 5, i am giving additional 15 to maintain space. I dont want to hard code.

Comment: https://github.com/cp-satish-v/MosaicLayoutDemo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, get three variables together depending on your needs. Those are the minimum spacing (Both InteritemSpacing and Line spacing - Should be same UXwise but you can change that in delegate methods if you like. The interitem space however must always be equal to `minimumSpacing`), edgeInsetPadding and the number of items you want in a row.

```
private var numberOfItemsInRow = 2

private var minimumSpacing = 5

private var edgeInsetPadding = 10
```

In your code, you have already defined your Edge Insets as:

```
 UIEdgeInsets(
            top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5
        )
```

The left and right insets are important for correctly determining the size of the item. left+right gives us a grand sum of 10. This should be assigned to `edgeInsetPadding` like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        let inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
        edgeInsetPadding = inset.left+inset.right
        return inset
    }
```

Now lets get to your `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. Update the following methods.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return minimumSpacing
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return minimumSpacing
    }
```

Now lets get to the main part. Modify your `sizeForItemAt` in `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` as:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = (Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width) - (numberOfItemsInRow - 1) * minimumSpacing - edgeInsetPadding) / numberOfItemsInRow
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }
```

And this is it. You now get two equal size tiles in 2x2 grid. If you want to change this in future, just change the `numberOfItemsInRow` variable to something else. Like 3 for 3x3.

Comment: Thank you, for explaining it so clearly.Your solution worked for me. But only problem which I faced is there is empty space at bottom of screen. I changed cell height to resolve this. Also I changed edge insets to 5 to fit it into 2 columns. Checked on iPhone 5, 6 and 6 plus.

Answer (score 3):

This will be done using the item size of the `collectionViewCell`

```
collectionView.delegate = self
```

```
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let padding = 5
        let width = (collectionView.frame.size.width - CGFloat(padding) * 2) / CGFloat(2)
        let height = width / 200 * 110 // or what height you want to do
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let padding: CGFloat =  20
        let size = self.view.frame.width - padding

        return CGSize(width: size/2, height: size/2+15)
    }
```

Comment: Cell will layout itself inside `CollectionView` so it's not a good idea to use `collectionView`'s parent `frame`.